# meaning of the range(row,-1,-1)

Tags: python, backtracking

I dont really get what the range(row,-1,-1), as well as the col one right under it, part means in the code below. I know that range exists of a start, end and step however in this particular example I really don't get what it means. It is used to check the upper diagonal of a matrix.

```
for i, j in zip(range(row, -1, -1),
                range(col, -1, -1)):
```

**Edit:**
Suppose that we would change the example above to this:

```
for i, j in zip(range(row, N, 1),
                range(col, -1, -1)):
```

What would this mean then?
Appreciate the help!

Comment: It starts at `row` and counts down to 0.  Remember that the ending value in a range is exclusive.  So, the zip will give you `(row,col)` then `(row-1,col-1)` then `(row-2,col-2)`, until one of the two goes to zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Okay but I still don't get why this has anything to do with the diagonal of a matrix?

Comment: @TimRoberts I understand! Thank you for your help I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you don't understand something, try it out in the console and print the result. The variables `row` and `col` we defined somewhere before.
Let's do a simple example:

```
row = 3
col = 4
for i, j in zip(range(row, -1, -1),range(col, -1, -1)):
    print(i,j)
```

It will print the following:

```
 3 4
 2 3
 1 2
 0 1
```

The `range()` is a built-in function that can accept 3 arguments: start, stop and step. In this case, `row` and `col` are the starting argument. And the iteration will go until zero (the stop value, -1, is not included) with step -1. And `zip` groups the two iterables into a tuple.

Comment: I get it this makes it a lot more cleare indeed! Thank you for your time and answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is most clearly understood by just looking at each part in isolation:

```py
row = 5
col = 5

print("range(row, -1, -1) on its own:")
for i in range(row, -1, -1):
    print(i)
    
    
print("range(col, -1, -1) on its own:")
for i in range(col, -1, -1):
    print(i)
    
print("zip on its own:")
for i, c in zip([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]):
    print(i, c)
```

Putting it all together:

```py
for i, j in zip(range(row, -1, -1),
                range(col, -1, -1)):
    print(i, j)
```

You can see how those coordinates line up with the diagonal:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | x |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 |  | x |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  | x |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  | x |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |  | x |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  | x |

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But now I have another question that is very similar. Suppose that we would replace -1 in ```range(row,-1,-1)``` to N and 1 so that would become ```range(row,N,1)``` and for col we keep it the same. It should be the lower diagonal but I don't really get how that would be the lower diagonal. If you would rather have that I edit my first question to this I will do so immidiatly but I wasn't sure so that's why I commented it.

Comment: Well, do you understand what the 3 parameters to `range` mean? Start by reading the documentation of `range`, then try applying the process I showed here (just print out the results, and try to understand the patterns you see)

Comment: Ohh okay I understand it already. It wasn't very smart of me. Thanks again and have a very nice day or evening!